# Why are this two operations returning the same?

Tags: php, date, hosting

Im trying to compare the creation date, and current date to do some operations depending on the outcome, the thing is, during my local development, everything was fine, all worked like a charm, but when i upload my script to the webhost, everything went down south, the following code

```
echo $date_modified = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file)); //date of modification of the file
```

Gives me the same result as

```
echo $current_time = date("F d Y H:i:s."); //the current time
```

¿ How is that even possible and why ?.

## EDIT

More on the subject, as i tried and tried to debug the script, i finally found out that, apparently, the sever is actively modifying the text file the php script is creating and placing 'null' on the file, ¿for what reason? i'm really not sure, but it seems like this is a problem related to the hosting, so i guess i'll have to search for a new hosting, as i really needed the file to be created to be able to cache some information without overloading the web service that was providing the information to fill in the file.

Comment: Linux on both ends, or a change in OS between the host/dev environment?

Comment: Mac on development, linux on the other end. but as i explain on the edit, it seems to be a problem with the server hosting the website.

Comment: What do you mean by "placing null on the file"?

Comment: well, whenever the script runs the file is created, but the content is set to a string 'null'. however, that never happen when i developed the script locally, an, as i found out reading more into it, it seems like its a problem related to the web hosting itself, they just don't like you going around creating text files, apparently.

Comment: Sounds like the file was created ok, but something in your code generates 'null' as a result to write to the file instead of the correct content. Could perhaps have something to do with MacOS being case insensitive while Linux is case sensitive when it comes to filenames.

Comment: it doesn't seem that way, as my mac drive is set to be case sensitive.

Comment: I still think it's worth checking that your PHP is generating the right content to write to the file since it would seem that PHP is generating the 'null' string that goes into the file, would be un-necessary work to change webhost and still have the same problem. Either way, good luck! :)

Comment: "well, whenever the script runs the file is created, but the content is set to a string 'null'."  --Can you explain this further?  Is this a result of your date comparison failing?  As for you host not wanting you to create files, well, find a new host :)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `$file` is in fact a file, and that when you attempt to open it you are using the proper path.

Comment: if `$file` were non-existent, `filemtime` would return false. If that was happening, `$date_modified` and `$current_time` would not hold the same values (`$date_modified` would contain "1969-12-31").

Answer (score 1):

`filemtime($file)` is returning the time the file was last modified (not "created", [see docs](http://php.net/filemtime)), which is probably the time the script was uploaded to your web host.

Comment: is the action of checking for the existence of the file considered a modification to the file ?

Comment: no.  _"returns the time when the data blocks of a file were being written to, that is, the time when the content of the file was changed." -php.net/filemtime_  As I said, though, uploading the file (which is the same as _writing a new file to the server_) certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

More on the subject, as i tried and tried to debug the script, i finally found out that the my script wasn't the problem, apparently, the sever is actively modifying the text file the php script is creating and placing 'null' on the file, ¿for what reason? i'm really not sure, but it seems like this is a problem related to the hosting, so i guess i'll have to search for a new hosting, as i really needed the file to be created to be able to cache some information without overloading the web service that was providing the information to fill in the file.

i'm sorry for wasting your time :/, i really am.